# $scope.$apply() is not updating the parent scope. Is this a binding issue?

Tags: angularjs

Perhaps this is a poor way of doing this, so I'm open to changing this.

I am implementing a drag and drop function through a `<drag-item>` directive and a `<drop-target>` directive. The `<drop-target>` directive successfully calls this function in the parent scope:

```
$scope.testAddSet = function(){
    console.log($scope.workoutItem); // gives me the last value
    $scope.thisMonth[0].sets.push($scope.workoutItem);
    $scope.$apply(); // needed to update the view, but uses the old value for workoutItem "test"
}; 

$scope.workoutItem = "test"; // value declared here
```

but my `<drag-item>` directive doesn't seem to update the value of `$scope.workoutItem`,

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="exercise in exercises">
   <drag-item workout-item="workoutItem" exercise="exercise"></drag-item>
</div>
```

`<drag-item>` directive:

```
angular.module('app.directives.dragItem', [])
  .directive('dragItem', function(){
    return { 
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        exercise: '=', 
        workoutItem: '='
      },
      templateUrl: "templates/dragTile.html",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.on('dragstart', function (event) {
          scope.workoutItem = scope.exercise.name; //correctly updates the local scope, but not the parent scope
          console.log(scope.workoutItem); 
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: `$scope.$apply()` inside event `dragstart` event will run digest & update will update binding correctly

Comment: @PankajParkar `$scope` wasn't recognised, and `scope.$apply()` didn't work.

Comment: Ahhh !! Got it, its issue related to `ng-repeat`, do try `$parent.workoutItem` instead of `workoutItem` like `<drag-item workout-item="$parent.workoutItem" exercise="exercise"></drag-item>`, for more detail refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35465962/2435473)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that you are defining `$scope.workoutItem` in your parent scope and then directive is creating another `workoutItem` property at directive's scope level. To avoid this, it is recomended that you use dots(.) to define your models. Please try something like:

`$scope.workout = {item: undefined}`

and then in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="exercise in exercises">
   <drag-item workout-item="workout.item" exercise="exercise"></drag-item>
</div>
```

I think this should solve your problem without modifying the directive itself.

Comment: In addition I had to use `scope.$apply()` at the end of my 'dragstart' event function after the reassignment (@PankajParkar).