# ng-change does not work in the table row generated by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple table row.

[image]

The row is generated by below code.

```
<tr ng-init="cacheChanged">
    <td>Expiration Period</td>
    <td ng-repeat="system in tableData.regions[0].systems">
        <input type="text" ng-model="system.cacheDuration" ng-change="cacheChanged=true">
        <span>h</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" ng-click="saveCache()" ng-disabled="!cacheChanged">Save</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When any of the four values changed, the save button is supposed to be enabled. However, it is still disabled all the time. Anyone knows why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you should use `$parent.cacheChanged` instead of `cacheChanged` variable. As `ng-repeat` does create child scope for each loop while rendering DOM. In short the `cacheChanged` variable inside `ng-repeat` is not same as that of `cacheChanged` used there on `button`.

**Markup**

```
<td ng-repeat="system in tableData.regions[0].systems">
    <input type="text" ng-model="system.cacheDuration" ng-change="$parent.cacheChanged=true">
    <span>h</span>
</td>
```

There is better way to go for it will be using `Dot rule` while defining `ng-model`, look at this detailed [**answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371114/2435473).

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks for your prompt reply! I will mark this as the answer later.

Comment: @Ealon Glad to know.. Thanks :)